# Weekend/Weekends

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary

I would be very happy if you help me to make clear some difficulties in using 'weekend'!

What is  the  difference between a weekend, the weekend, weekends (can we say the weekends?)

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please also visit [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Yes, you can say "the weekends", as in "I need a cat sitter for the next four weekends. (Friday evening through Sunday evening)."

Answer (score 1):

Some examples, these four sentences should be understandable in their simplicity

> I'm going for **a weekend**
>   *I'm going for one weekend (does not specify which weekend)*
>
> I went for **a weekend**
>   *I went for one weekend (does not specify which weekend)*
>
> I'm going for **the weekend**.
>   *I'm going this coming weekend*
>
> I went for **the weekend**.
>   *I was there last (past) weekend*

Following shows slight difference in meanings even though "the weekend" is used

> We are going to the Hamptons for **the weekend**
>   We go to the Hamptons **this weekend**
>   *We will be in the Hamptons this weekend*
>
> We go to the Hamptons for **the weekend**
>   We go to the Hamptons on **weekends**
>   *We habitually go to the Hamptons during weekends*
>
> I ride on **the weekends**.
>   *I habitually ride horses during the weekends*

A bit trickier is

> We come to the Hampton for **the weekends**
>   *We come to the Hamptons because there are nice things happening during the weekends*

similar to

> I come to this restaurant for the food.
>   *The reason I go to the restaurant is the great food*

Answer (score 0):

Examples of use:
1. I'm going home for the weekend.
2. I stay there from Monday to Friday and go home for the weekends.
3. Cycling is my favorite weekend activity.
4. I often go cycling at weekends.
5. I will be available for the weekends of 1st/2nd and 8th/9th.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Jackson! Does it mean that there is no option with an article 'a'? It means we always should say "the weekend" or "weekends and NOT "a weekend"?

Comment: Note that #4 doesn't sound right to me (American English speaker). It should be "I often go cycling **on** weekends."

Comment: @Martha Do you people say *I often go cycling at **the** weekends?*

Comment: "At the weekend" is BrE. Although "the" is used, it is a non specific weekend being described, equivalent to AmE "on weekends".

Comment: @Ustanak: "at the weekends" is even worse than "at weekends". A weekend is two days long, so "at" is just not the right preposition.

Comment: @Peter Yes. I'm learning the BrE, that's why I asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`A weekend` A non-specific weekend.

> It will take me a weekend to finish checking my emails.

`The weekend` A specific weekend. Usually refers to the last or this weekend.

> I went to the beach on the weekend. (probably last weekend)
>
> I'm going to the beach on the weekend. (probably this weekend)
>
> I'm going to the beach on the first weekend of June. (specified)

`The weekends/Weekends` General and specific weekends.

> I go to the beach on the weekends/weekends. (general)
>
> I'm going to go to the beach on two weekends next month. (specific)